# Adding useCallback or useMemo to recursive material treeview

Tags: reactjs, recursion, react-hooks

Im wondering the best way to implement a useCallback() or useMemo() for better performance in material ui's treeview component. This example is small but, my real version could have 100's of directories...

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TreeView from '@mui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@mui/lab/TreeItem';

const data = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Parent',
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Child - 1',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Child - 3',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Child - 4',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

export default function RichObjectTreeView() {
  const renderTree = (nodes) => (
    <TreeItem key={nodes.id} nodeId={nodes.id} label={nodes.name}>
      {Array.isArray(nodes.children)
        ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node))
        : null}
    </TreeItem>
  );

  return (
    <TreeView
      aria-label="rich object"
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpanded={['root']}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      sx={{ height: 110, flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, overflowY: 'auto' }}
    >
      {renderTree(data)}
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is `data` static? If so, you can change `renderTree(data)` into `useMemo(() => renderTree(data), [data])` which will call `renderTree` only once. If `data` can mutate and you need to do a deep comparison things get more complicated.

Comment: ^ Note that you do still have to follow the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Eg. Don't call `useMemo` as part of a conditional render and don't call it inside loops. To better demonstrate that the above is still following the rules you might want to store the return value in a variable outside the JSX first. `const treeItems = useMemo(() => renderTree(data), [data])`, then place `{treeItems}` inside your JSX.

Comment: @3limin4t0r - yes the data will mutate. Interesting ok.